# Using Fetch in React to fetch data from server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I am trying to fetch data from the server(Node.js) with the following code:

```
componentDidMount = () => {
fetch('http://localhost:3000/numberofjobs')
.then(response => response.json())
.then(numberOfJobs => {
      console.log(numberOfJobs)
})
}
```

That's my route in Node:

```
const handleNumberOfJobs = (req, res, Register) => {
 Register.find({})
  .then(users =>  {
  const total = users.reduce((sum, { numberOfJobs }) => sum + 
  numberOfJobs, 0);
  console.log(total);
  })
  .then(response => res.json(response))
}
```

One problem I'm having is the Front-end console.log is not showing up in the console, and I don't know why. In the server side, when the pages loads it does console.log the sum and everything, so it's working so I believe I am doing something wrong with React. I want to bring this info to my front-end so I could display it on the page.

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Side note: You're not checking for errors in that `fetch` call. This is such a common mistake that [I wrote it up on my anemic little blog](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html).

Comment: Other than the error checking on the `fetch`, which isn't likely to be the problem, that looks fine other than it's a bit unusual to make `componentDidMount` an arrow function like that. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/). (You can use `setTimeout` to simulate `fetch`.)

Comment: Try adding `.catch(error => console.log(error))`. It's likely throwing an error somehow and not reaching the console.log you have in your `.then`.

Comment: @JamesIves - Normally, though, you get an "unhandled rejection" error in the console...

Comment: Are you sure, `.then(response => res.json(response))` would return response.  I think returning response (`res.json(response)`) in the first `then`, where you have `console.log` would work.

Comment: Guys, thanks a lot for your help, actually I found the problem, instead of returning the total, I was console.logging it! After I changed it, it started fetching in react. Thanks again!!

Comment: @Dhirendra I will try that too! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**

There's a mistake in how you use arrow functions' implicit returns in your *server side* code.

The fix is to just add a `return total;` in the first `.then(...)` handler.

**Details**

First off, let's get it out: I agree with the comments on not neglecting error checks! (Be it `fetch` or anything else.)

Anyway: You use arrow functions in your `.then(...)` handlers. But that last statement in the first one is `console.log(total)`. The return value of that call is `undefined`, which becomes the implicit return value of your arrow function. The promise then passes this on as the value of `response` in your second `.then(...)` handler. (You could verify that by adding `console.log(response)` in the second `.then(...)` handler.

The fix is to just add a `return total;` in the first `.then(...)` handler:

```
const handleNumberOfJobs = (req, res, Register) => {
  Register
    .find({})
    .then(users => {
      const total = users.reduce(
        (sum, { numberOfJobs }) => sum + 
            numberOfJobs, 0
      );
      console.log(total);   // <-- returns undefined
      return total;         // <-- pass on to next promise
    })
    .then(response => {
      // console.log(response);  // if you're curious
      res.json(response)
    })
  }
}
```

Personal hint: Indent / lint your code for easier maintenance.